# How to change color in particular graph

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I Want to change color in particular graph in canvas js 
please help me

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("incomeHouseHold", {
      animationEnabled: true,
      theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
      title: {
        text: ""
      },
      axisY: {
        title: ""
      },
      data: [{
        type: "column",
        legendMarkerColor: "grey",
        dataPoints: [{
            y: 100878,
            label: "5%"
          },
          {
            y: 266455,
            label: "15%"
          },
          {
            y: 569709,
            label: "55%"
          },
          {
            y: 158400,
            label: "5%"
          },
          {
            y: 142503,
            label: "10%"
          },
          {
            y: 142503,
            label: "10%"
          }
        ]
      }]
    });
    chart.render();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can add color: "#color" after label such as

```
[{
    y: 100878,
    label: "5%",
    color : "#B0D0B0"
},
```

is this code based on canvas.js not chart.js?

yours tagged the post as `chart.js` while the code is structured in canvas.js